# How to get different prompt look for root and regular user

Tags: linux, macos, command-line, bash

My `.bash_profile` has different styles of prompt for regular user and root but in order it to work the `.bash_profile` should be reloaded every time I switch users. How can I achieve this?

Can I make the command `. ~/.bash_profile` to be executed every time I execute `su` command in order to change the prompt look for root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the custom prompt of `root` in his `.bash_profile`, not in your regular user's profile.
Usually this is the default setup anyway, without manually having to edit it.

Note that when you use `su` without arguments,
it doesn't read `root`'s rc files, that's why the prompt doesn't change.
To make `su` read `root`'s rc files, use `su -` (with a dash as parameter).
That way, normally, you should see `root`'s custom prompt instead of your user's.